# Can't link against static library with Mingw on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, g++, mingw-w64, gmp

I have installed the [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/) and try to cross-compile with mingw-w64-posix.

My Library is in /usr/local/lib.

My compile command looks like the following:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix src/factorial.cpp -o bin/factorial.win.o -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lgmp -lgmpxx
```

It throws an undefined reference error:
*(I can remove the whole block from `-L....`, same error. Seems like the library doesnt link for some reason)*

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccxY03WS.o:factorial.cpp:(.text$_ZN23__gmp_binary_multiplies4evalEP12__mpz_structPKS0_S3_[_ZN23__gmp_binary_multiplies4evalEP12__mpz_structPKS0_S3_]+0x27): undefined reference to `__gmpz_mul'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccxY03WS.o:factorial.cpp:(.text$_ZN23__gmp_binary_multiplies4evalEP12__mpz_structPKS0_l[_ZN23__gmp_binary_multiplies4evalEP12__mpz_structPKS0_l]+0x26): undefined reference to `__gmpz_mul_si'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccxY03WS.o:factorial.cpp:(.text$_ZN10__gmp_exprIA1_12__mpz_structS1_E7init_siEl[_ZN10__gmp_exprIA1_12__mpz_structS1_E7init_siEl]+0x1a): undefined reference to `__gmpz_init_set_si'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccxY03WS.o:factorial.cpp:(.text$_ZN10__gmp_exprIA1_12__mpz_structS1_EC1EOS2_[_ZN10__gmp_exprIA1_12__mpz_structS1_EC1EOS2_]+0x2e): undefined reference to `__gmpz_init'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccxY03WS.o:factorial.cpp:(.text$_ZN10__gmp_exprIA1_12__mpz_structS1_ED1Ev[_ZN10__gmp_exprIA1_12__mpz_structS1_ED1Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `__gmpz_clear'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

### However if i change my compiler to `g++` instead everything works fine.

Comment: Dude ... *WHAT'S THE UNDEFINED REFERENCE*???  Please "Edit" your post, and copy/paste the ERROR MESSAGE!

Comment: Im sry, i miss click that one

Comment: It looks like you included the header as C++ code, and the library as C code, and the mangled C++ names don't match the basic C names.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I include the gmpxx.h header (which is the basic gmp c++ header) and i link against both the c++ aswell as the c static library of gmp

Comment: I don't think there's a standard for C++ function name decoration, so different compilers could be incompatible.

Comment: It is strange that you are trying to give the output a name that ends in `.o`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK -

1. The link errors (__gmpz_init, __gmpz_clear, etc.) are GMP "internals".  They're supposed to come from libgmp, the C-language base library.
2. The code that's referencing them (.text$*ZN23__gmp_binary_multiplies4evalEP12__mpz_structPKS0_S3*[*ZN23__gmp_binary_multiplies4evalEP12__mpz_structPKS0_S3*], etc.) is "name mangled" C++.
3. I suspect the *problem* is that your "gmpxx" library was built with a *different* C++ compiler, that has a *different* "name mangling" convention than MinGW.

SOLUTION:

Download the complete libGMP source (e.g. from https://gmplib.org/, and rebuild EVERYTHING (including libgmpxx) with your libmingw-w64-posix++ C++ cross-compiler.

---

ADDENDUM:

I downloaded gmp-6.2.1 source, and found __gmpz_clear here:

gmp-6.2.1\gmp-h.in

```
#define mpz_clear __gmpz_clear
__GMP_DECLSPEC void mpz_clear (mpz_ptr);
```

"gmp-h.in" is a template used by the project's "autoconf", to generate the libGMP source files for the specified target environment.

Which, in turn, means:

1. The project you started out with (in your original question) wasn't configured for MinGW

... and ...

2. You didn't run "configure" correctly when you tried building from source.

SUGGESTION:

1. Try building libGMP from source again.  DELETE everything, re-extract from the libGMP tarball, and carefully follow the INSTALL instructions:

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   make check       <= VERY IMPORTANT!!
   make install
   ```
2. I'm curious about your build environment (Windows?  Linux?), compiler (exact MinGW version) and target (if you're building on a Windows workstation, do you want to run your GMP app as a Windows .exe)?

Comment: That sounds about right...Do you know what flags to set for the configre file?I looked in the docs and it isnt very simple for me to find the type i need to set

Comment: Sorry.  If you really need to "cross compile", then you'll just need to read the README, take your best shot ... and see what happens.  If you encounter problems or have specific questions, please feel free to ask a new question.  But it sounds like you now have the answer to this question.

Comment: The missing symbols are referenced from factorial.cpp, not from libgmpxx (which only contains a few I/O functions). If there were missing symbols from libgmpxx, the first thing to do would be to reorder the flags: `-lgmpxx` before `-lgmp`.